# In how many ways can $n$ items be arranged in two boxes with a restriction

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Given $n$ items that can be arranged in $k$ ways in one box, if we add a second, different box with $m$ spaces available to any of the $n$ items, in how many ways in total can we now arrange the $n$ items?

The problem is that the items' placement is restricted in the first box in an unknown way (we only know in how many ways they can be arranged in the first box) - this means if we were to take $i$ specific items out of the first box, we cannot calculate in how many ways we can arrange the remaining $(n - i)$ items in the first box.

Is there a combinatorial solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not without more information about what restrictions are in place when the first box is not full, and possibly even when it is full.

For example, suppose that when the box is not full, the items must still be in an arrangement that can be obtained by simply removing elements from one of the $k$ valdi full arrangements. Consider the example $n = 3, k = 2, m = 2$. And let the 3 elements be $a, b, c$.

First suppose the valid full arrangements are $abc$ and $acb$. Then we can have the following arrangements:
$$\begin{matrix} abc|\cdot\cdot & acb|\cdot\cdot & ab\cdot|c\ \cdot & ab\cdot|\cdot c\\
ac\cdot|b\ \cdot & ac\cdot|\cdot b & a\cdot c|b\ \cdot & a\cdot c|\cdot b\\
a\cdot b|c\ \cdot  & a\cdot b|\cdot c & \cdot\ bc|a\ \cdot & \cdot\ bc|\cdot\ a \\\cdot\ cb|a\ \cdot & \cdot\ cb|\cdot a & a\cdot\cdot|bc & a\cdot\cdot|cb \\ \cdot\ b\ \cdot|ac & \cdot\ b\ \cdot|ca & \cdot\ c\ \cdot|ab & \cdot\ c\ \cdot|ba \\
\cdot\cdot c|ab & \cdot\cdot c|ba & \cdot\cdot b|ac & \cdot\cdot b|ca\end{matrix}$$
or 24 total. Now suppose instead that the valid full arrangements are $abc$ and $bca$. Then we have:
$$\begin{matrix} abc|\cdot\cdot & bca|\cdot\cdot & ab\cdot|c\ \cdot & ab\cdot|\cdot c\\
bc\cdot|a\ \cdot & bc\cdot|\cdot a & a\cdot c|b\ \cdot & a\cdot c|\cdot b\\
b\cdot a|c\ \cdot & b\cdot a|\cdot c & \cdot\ bc|a\ \cdot & \cdot\ bc|\cdot\ a\\
\cdot\ ca|b\ \cdot & \cdot\ ca|\cdot b & a\cdot\cdot|bc & a\cdot\cdot|cb\\
b\cdot\cdot|ca & b\cdot\cdot|ac & \cdot\ b\ \cdot|ac & \cdot\ b\ \cdot|ca \\ \cdot\ c\ \cdot|ba & \cdot\ c\ \cdot|ab & \cdot\cdot c|ab & \cdot\cdot c|ba \\ \cdot\cdot a|bc & \cdot\cdot a|cb\end{matrix}$$
or 26 total.

And that is supposing a rule that is not defined. Another possibility is that if fewer than $n$ items are in the first box, then there are no restrictions on the arrangement, which gives other values.

So as it stands the problem is ill-defined, and so admits no definite solution.